# SQLAlchemy: Session commits/flushes successfully but data does not appear in database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have encountered a problem with sqlalchemy where the session seems to commit successfully, but the data does not appear in the underlying database table. However, when printing the committed items before and after the commit, the data shows. Basically, what I am trying to do is assign an item (the row to be updated) and then update the calculated value in the database.

Any tips are appreciated! Apologies in advance if the code below is not the cleanest - I have just recently begun to teach myself python.

```
query_od_matrix = session.query(dr.ODMatrix).order_by(dr.ODMatrix.distance)

def generate_bins(qry):
mx = session.query(sa.func.max(dr.ODMatrix.origin_stops_id)).scalar()
# Testing
# print mx

for o in range(1, mx+1): # o=origin, d=destination
    query = qry.filter(dr.ODMatrix.origin_stops_id == o)
    dest_id = []
    dest_dist = []

    for row in query:
        # Testing
        # print row.origin_stops_id, row.destination_stops_id, row.distance
        dest_id.append(row.destination_stops_id)
        dest_dist.append(row.distance)

    # Testing
    # print dest_id, dest_dist
    no_items = len(dest_id)

    for d in range(0, no_items):
        # Testing
        # print d, dest_id[d], dest_dist[d]

        if d == 0: # First item
            lower = 0
            upper = 0.5 * (float(dest_dist[d]) +  float(dest_dist[d+1]))
        elif d == no_items-1: # Last item
            lower = 0.5 * (float(dest_dist[d]) +  float(dest_dist[d-1]))
            upper = None
        else:
            lower = 0.5 * (float(dest_dist[d]) +  float(dest_dist[d-1]))
            upper = 0.5 * (float(dest_dist[d]) +  float(dest_dist[d+1]))

        item = dr.ODMatrix(origin_stops_id=o, destination_stops_id=dest_id[d])
        # Testing
        # print d, dest_id[d], lower, upper
        # print dest_id[d], item.destination_stops_id
        item.bin_from = lower
        item.bin_to = upper
        # Testing
        # session.dirty
        # print item.origin_stops_id, item.destination_stops_id, item.bin_from, item.bin_to
        session.commit()
        # session.flush()
        # Testing
        # session.dirty
        # print item.origin_stops_id, item.destination_stops_id, item.bin_from, item.bin_to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add item to the session before commit

```
item = dr.ODMatrix(origin_stops_id=o, destination_stops_id=dest_id[d])
item.bin_from = lower
item.bin_to = upper
session.add(item)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Sometimes I feel so stupid. However, while this works it creates new rows. is there any way to update the existing ones?

Comment: To update existing ones just set new values and commit, like this `item = session.query(dr.ODMatrix).first(); item.bin_form = new_value; session.commit()`